# Confusion about child nodes of documenElement in XML DOM

Tags: xml, dom

Consider this xml as:-

book.xml

```
<bookstore>
    <book category="cooking">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book category="children">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category="web">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>49.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category="web" cover="paperback">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

Now I get a XMLDOM object to be used in JavaScript using Firefox XML Parser using XMLHttpRequest.

Say the XML DOM is stored in variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");

x=xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;

for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
      document.write(x[i].nodeName);
      document.write("<br />");
  }
</script>
```

outputs:-

```
#text
book
#text
book
#text
book
#text
book
#text
```

A total of 9 child nodes. Howcome ? I see that `<bookstore>` has only 4 child nodes as `<book>`.

Please help me in understanding this.

Thanks.
Aiwee

Answer (score 3):

The "#text" nodes contain the whitespace between the "book" nodes.

Comment: Hi,

Whitespace...makes sense. Just counted using whitespace approach, I think newline is also included. Right ?

Is this due to Firefox browser ? And only for browsers or it extends to XML parsing libraries too.

Aiwee